# What does the white folder mean in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution-explorer

[image]

How can I do it too? I want to be able to upload images to my MVC application.

Comment: It seems to be blank

Comment: That folder was excluded from project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folder is present in the local system, but is not included in the current project so you have to right click and add the folder in the project